# spf13-vim tagbar is not working

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, ctags, tagbar

I have already mounted ctags, but it still not working at all. I pressed ,tt , and nothing happened. Is that any way to solve this problem in spf13-vim? Did Anyone suffer the same problem as me?

Comment: Who knows? Spf13 adds and changes too many things for anybody not familiar with that crap to help you reliably, and you probably don't know Vim enough (thanks to spf13) to explain your issue or narrow it down to something that can bedebugged.

Answer (score 0):

Have you remapped your `<Leader>` key to `,`?

The *tagbar toggle* in spf13 is `<Leader>tt`, and the leader key is `\` by default.

Try to toggle the tagbar with `\tt`. Alternatively, add `let mapleader=","` to your .vimrc.

Comment: I have tried \tt already, and I also checked that leader is mapped to , in .vimrc.

Answer (score 0):

I found that tagbar plugin is not installed if `ctags` command is not available on spf13 installation.

Search tagbar in installed plugins list: `:BundleList` then `/tagbar`.
If it's not found, install ctags first.

Running `:BundleInstall` within vim and restarting vim will fix the problem.